# How to add comma separator in status bar for sum in Microsoft Excel 365 MSO 64-bit?

Tags: excel

I would like to have comma separator for sum in status bar (see image). Is it possible?
[image: Excel status bar sum]

Comment: Format the selected cells with a comma

Answer (score 1):

As @Rory suggested, you have to have cells formatted:
[image]

[image]